# Throwing a die - what is a probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I read a probability book that says:

Let us roll 2 symmetrical cubes. Determine the probability of an event that a different number on both cubes has fallen?

The solution start with writing of $\Omega$.
$$\Omega = \{ (i,j):i,j=1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$$
My question is why Omega isn't filled with set of $\{i,j\}$ because if I have 2 the same dice why I count event (3,4) and (4,3)?

Comment: because the probability of (4,4) is 1/36 and probability of (3,4) is 1/18 even if the dice are the same, indistingushable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In determining probability using 2 dice rolls why are permutations (x,x) not counted twice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239315/in-determining-probability-using-2-dice-rolls-why-are-permutations-x-x-not-cou)

Answer (score 1):

The space is determined, in part, by whether the dice are distinguishable or not.  Once you set that, the rest is easy.

If the dice are indistinguishable, then the outcomes are:  $(1,1), (1,2), \ldots , (6,6)$ and of *course* these are not equally likely, as governed by simply binomial distribution.  For instance, it is twice as likely you get $(1,2)$ than $(1,1)$.

Comment: Oolala, are you saying that if the dice are visually indistinguishable, then (3,4) is same probability as (4,4) ?

Comment: @Kostas:  No... of course not.  Note that not all outcomes in an outcome space need have the same probability.

Comment: How are you going to determine those probabilities if not by saying that P(12) = P'(1,2) + P'(2,1) where P' is probabilities calculated with distinguishable dice?

Comment: You can mathematically incorporate indistinguishability, generally by dividing by the multiplicity.  But even if you *do* first consider the distinguishable case first, you needn't adhere to it once you have the final space that is relevant.